# jQuery / CSS create linear gradient with only one color

Tags: css, colors, linear-gradients

In CSS, linear gradient css looks like:

```
   background-image: linear-gradient(blue, lightblue);
```

This starts the gradient at blue, and ends at lightblue. Not actually pretty, but it serves as an example.

Now, what if you only have the start color? What if you start with a passed parameter for color (imagine it's passed in an MVC ViewModel)? For example, you may have been passed a value of 'red', and you would like to have a linear gradient from that starting 'red' to some subtly lighter color of red to make a nice gradient?

Would you need to know, or convert, 'red' into hex values, and then generate the gradient stop color by manipulation of the hex number? Is there a 'normal' way to do this? Ie

1. some trick to convert 'red' to a hex value like #A11634
2. some trick to apply some math to 'make A11634 a subtly lighter color'?

OR

3. some gradient trick to automagically create a gradient with one color, to a lighter version of that color?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a very simple solution to save you the hassles of manipulating the colours; instead of passing the named colour to the gradient, set it as the `background-colour` of your element with a white gradient as the `background-image`, fading from completely transparent to however much you want to lighten your base colour by.

Here's an example using the `background` shorthand property with the colour transitioning from bottom to top:

```css
div{
    background-image:linear-gradient(0deg,rgba(255,255,255,0),rgba(255,255,255,.75));
    height:100px;
    margin:0 0 10px;
}
#red{
  background-color:red;
}
#green{
  background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<div id="red"></div>
<div id="green"></div>
```

Comment: I don't see any gradient...?? I'm using Chrome

Comment: Perhaps:     background-color: red;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, white -5%, rgba(255,0,0,0));

Comment: What browser are you using? If you're using an older one, you may need to prefix the gradient. See http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gradients I'll increase the alpha of the white at the end to make it more apparent, just in case that's the issue.

Comment: I have changed your gradient to make it more visible. And also split the background in individual properties; I believe it is easier to use this way. Good answer, by the way.

Comment: Thanks, @vals, you beat me to it :)

Comment: Chrome. No joy. I did use your idea though... http://jsfiddle.net/devfingers/8pxtzjbg/

Comment: What version of Chrome? v26+ should be able to display the gradient using that syntax.

Comment: Chrome updates automagically, but let me check... v 42.0.2311.90 m

Comment: Exactly the same as me. Don't understand why you can't see it. I'll up the alpha of the last white again to make it even more apparent.

Comment: lol - now I get a gradient - two infact - one red, and below, in green; both nice looking gradients

Comment: Perhaps it's an issue with this 'snippet' tool?

Comment: Nope, all has been working fine for me when viewing the snippets, must have just been a display issue on your end ;) Glad you got it sorted though.